# Use Firebase Phone Authentication with Coroutines

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I want to create a signing activity in my app using Firebase phone authentication. The authentication has three phases:

1. Sending verification code with `PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)`
2. Verify the code with `PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId!!, code)`
3. Sign in the user with `auth.signInWithCredential(credential)`

I want to use Coroutines to handle the signing process. I know how to handle code verification using `await()`, which wrap the `Task` returned by `auth.signInWithCredential(credential)`.

My problem is with `PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)` function which is a `void` function. I must use callbacks to handle this method.

```
val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
      .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .setCallbacks(callback)
      .build()
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
```

where `callbacks` is:

```
callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                Timber.i("onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                Timber.i(e,"onVerificationFailed")
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                Timber.i("onCodeSent:$verificationId")
                storedVerificationId = verificationId
                resendToken = token
            }
        }
```

The question is: is there a way to use `await()` with `verifyPhoneNumber` function?
Otherwise, how can I use coroutines with callbacks to block the function until callbacks triggered?

Comment: Isn't `callbacks` already doing what you want ?

Comment: @NaveenNiraula but callbacks is not blockable, my viewmodel must observe the result of the function

Comment: Why don't you put your code inside `onVerificationCompleted() { }` or am I not getting what you want to do ?

Comment: @NaveenNiraula yes i can do that, but the other function `verifyPhoneNumber` will finish before callbacks fired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) to wrap Firebase callback into a coroutine suspend function like this:

```
sealed class PhoneAuthResult {
    data class VerificationCompleted(val credentials: PhoneAuthCredential) : PhoneAuthResult()
    data class CodeSent(val verificationId: String, val token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken)
        : PhoneAuthResult()
}

private suspend fun performPhoneAuth(
    phoneNumber: String,
    firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth): PhoneAuthResult = 
    suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        val callback = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                Timber.i("onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
                cont.resume(
                    PhoneAuthResult.VerificationCompleted(credential)
                )
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                Timber.i(e, "onVerificationFailed")
                cont.resumeWithException(e)
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                Timber.i("onCodeSent:$verificationId")
                cont.resume(
                    PhoneAuthResult.CodeSent(verificationId, token)
                )
            }
        }
        
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setCallbacks(callback)
            .build()

        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below solution for this problem

First of all, you must define an interface `FcmService`

```
interface FcmService {
     suspend fun initFcmToken() : Flow<String>
}
```

for next section define `FcmServiceImpl`

```
class FcmServiceImpl : FcmService {
override suspend fun initFcmToken(): Flow<String> =
    callbackFlow {
       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(
            OnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    Logger.error(
                        "Device Manager" +
                                "Fetching FCM registration token failed" +
                                task.exception
                    )
                    return@OnCompleteListener
                }
                if (task.isComplete) {
                    trySend(task.result)
                }
            })
        awaitClose { cancel() }
    }
 }
```

and then for use

```
fcmService.initFcmToken().collectLatest {

//  your token is here

}
```

**I hope help**